# Looping/printing over a list in R

Tags: r, list, loops, printing

Let's suppose I have a simple list

```
 v <- list(vec1=c(1,2,3), vec2=c(3,4,5, 6))
```

I would like to loop over this list and perform some function on its element, so that as an output I get both: name of that particular element and output of the function. For example:

```
for (i in v)
{print(sd(i)) 
}
```

In this case, the output is:

```
 [1] 1
 [1] 1.290994
```

But I would like to see something like this:

```
 $vec1
 [1] 1
 $vec2
 [1] 1.290994
```

So that I can easily spot to which element each output refers, if I have many elements within my list. I know it has sth with the function `names()` to do, but I can't make it work.

Comment: `lapply(v, sd)`

Comment: Thank you, this works fine indeed! However, is there a way to do this with a some sort of a loop or modify lapply(), as in fact I have more complicated examples? For example, a list of data frames, on which I would like to run a correlation matrix of particular columns?

Answer (score 1):

Using the function `names()` and outputting a list:

```
result<-list()
for (i in 1:length(v))
{result[[i]]=sd(v[[i]])
}
names(result)<-names(v)
```

The downside of this method is that it will assign the wrong names if the resulting list is smaller or greater than the original list (for example, if you add a `next` statement on the loop or otherwise skip an element).

If possible, a much easier solution is to follow d.b's comment.